# Socket.emit (Socket.io) losing performance when switching tab?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, streaming, delay

I'm coding a simple web voice chat with node.js and socket.io, and I've noticed that when doing this:

```
socket.emit("chunk", JSON.stringify(pcm))
```

And unfocusing the tab where it's running, the browser saves the data it should be sending and then emit like 5 or 6 of those chunks at the same time (which causes a spike in node.js and creates a huge delay in the stream)

However this does not happen when using [websockets](https://github.com/websockets/ws). Is there any way to fix this? I would prefer to use socket.io instead of [websockets](https://github.com/websockets/ws).

Than you!

Comment: Are you using timers to send data from an unattended tab?  Many modern browsers slow down or stop timers in tabs that are not foreground (for performance and battery consumption reasons).

Comment: Not timers. I use that whenever the [onaudioprocess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode/onaudioprocess) fires, but I use the same code with websockets and it works fine, the only thing that I change is the emit method

Comment: Looking at the engine.io code on Github (which socket.io uses for its transports), there are timers involved in doing pings and sending data.  I wonder if the slow-down in timers for background tabs is messing you up.  This sounds like something you might want to report an issue on [their Github site](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io).